# how to retrieve the names of servers that i can connect to..?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

my system is connected Trhough LAN..

totally four systems connected. and all systems having MS SQl server installed in it.

now i need to retreive that - which all server's i can connect to..?

server names -  for connection string...!!

thanx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SMO for this. Example here http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=45

Or [System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();
```

Check this open source project for more: http://dataconnectionsuite.codeplex.com/